# Xamarin Studio f# project fails to build on OSX

Tags: f#, xamarin-studio

I've created a simple xamarin studio f# project and and f# unit project. When I build I get

```
unknown-file(1,1): Error FS2020: The assembly
 'Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/NUnit/nunit.framework.dll'
  is listed on the command line. 
  Assemblies should be referenced using a command line flag such as 
  '-r'. (FS2020) (FRXUI.Spec)
```

I have made no source code changes after generating the template projects.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the `space` in the path to the file, the reference should read

`/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/NUnit/nunit.framework.dll`

There is currently a known issue [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding/issues/111)

You can also work around it by using nuget, I almost always use [fsunit](https://github.com/dmohl/FsUnit) with NUnit for unit tests in F#.  If you don't already have it, you can also get [monodevelop-nuget-addin](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin) which makes installation of these packages pretty easy.

Comment: I had no idea there was a nuget plugin! +1

Answer (score 3):

I got this too. I worked around it by replacing the reference to `nunit.framework` in my test project with a version built from source.